# Python overlapping processes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I've run into some weird behavior and and I am not exactly sure how to address this issue.

**Overview:**

I have a Linux/Ubuntu server with a API that receives thousands of records an hour. These records are stored in a table in my database, we'll call it a staging table, where the records are processed at a later time.

I run a cron every minute to grab x records from this staging table and process them with a simple python script.

**Problem:**

Lets say this script can process x records per minute. Then each process finishes before the next one begins. However, if I increase the number of records I'm trying to process to 2x then the cron that fired at time 0 has not finished processing it's batch of records when the next cron that fires at time 1 starts. So now we have two running processes, the cron that fired at time 0 which is almost done and the cron which fired at time 1 which just started.

This is where something unexpected happens. I have a simple function in the script to process and save processed results to another table. When there are two scripts that are overlapping (as described above), these records each get saved twice to the database. If only one process is running it only gets saved once.

I'm scratching my head and not sure how this is possible since each script should be independent. I didn't think it would be useful to include code since it's literally just a cron firing a script to 1. pull records from staging table. 2. make changes to those records 3. save those changed records to new table.

If you think it's helpful, I would be glad to upload code to the question. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: This staging table, are you using locks for reading? So only one of the script can read at a time? I have another suggestions for you if you would like to know :D

Comment: Yes, I considered this, I have a column in the staging table labeled 'final' so when a script finishes processing it marks that record as final and is ignored by potentially overlapping scripts. Also, when records are duplicated their timestamp is nearly identical suggesting it's not two scripts processing the same record at different times. Would love to hear your other suggestion.

Comment: Redis queuing was my second suggestion.

Comment: "Also, when records are duplicated their timestamp" - This is strange :/

Comment: When records are written twice to the second table after being processed their id are sequential.

Comment: Which means they are written by both the scripts. Then locking can be a better option or use redis queues.

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right. damn. Have been struggling with this for a long time and not sure why I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes all it needs is an outside eye :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Use MySQL Read Locks

If you even have a doubt that this might be happening with your multiple scripts initiation then you should use read locks. [Read About Locks Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/)

> MySQL allows a client session to acquire a table lock explicitly for preventing other sessions from accessing the table during a specific period. A client session can acquire or release table locks only for itself. It cannot acquire or release table locks for other sessions.

**Solution 2:** Use Queuing with Redis Presistence for your Staging Table

Redis acts as a queue before your consumer scripts and will allow chunk by chunk delivery.

> RQ (Redis Queue) is a simple Python library for queueing jobs and processing them in the background with workers. It is backed by Redis and it is designed to have a low barrier to entry. It can be integrated in your web stack easily.